# Unconditional bash exit after receiving exit code other than 0 from BTEQ

Tags: sql, bash, unix, teradata

I have a simple bash script with following bteq;

```
bteq <<EOF!
    .set width 255
    .set format off
    .set titledashes off

    .logon ${HOST}/${USER}, ${PASSWORD};    

    .export report file=test_file.rpt;

    SELECT count(*) from test_db.test_table;   /*this table contains 90 rows in my case*/

    .IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .EXIT ERRORCODE;        
    .IF ACTIVITYCOUNT = 0 THEN .GOTO ALLOK

    .LOGOFF;
    .EXIT 3;

    .LABEL ALLOK;
    .LOGOFF;
    .EXIT 0;

EOF!

/*Now if the above bteq returns 0,(i.e. RET_FLAG = 0) the below code executes 
with RC (return code) = 0 but if it returns values other than 0 below code doesn't executes and finally bash exits.*/  

RET_FLAG=$?   
print_msg "RET_FLAG: $RET_FLAG "   /*when return code other than 0 this line is not printed*/

if [ $? -gt 0 ];
then
     print_msg "Hello world get succeed" /* printing function */
     exit 1
fi
```

I have worked whole day to figure out, but still no progress. Help from anybody out there would save my night.Thanks in advance.

Comment: recall that each command executed resets the value of `$?`. In this case, don't test `$?`  test `$RET_FLAG`. The `$?` holds now the '0' exit code from `print_msg`. OR maybe your `exit 3` in bteq isn't work as you think. Add an `echo RC=$?` immediately after `EOF1`. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks @shellter, echo RC=$? prints 0 if bteq exit with 0 status and 3(RC=3) if it exist with exit status 3. I was thinking, may be bash interpreted RC (return code) = 3 as error from bteq, thus script may have exited.

Comment: yes, 0 return code means "Good". any other number means "Bad" . Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

In the if condition, please use RET_FLAG -gt 0. Instead of $?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but even without if condition the same thing happens. script exit with RC = 3 if bteq exit with status 3 and script run successfully if bteq exit with status 0

Answer (score 0):

Ok I posted the question and I found the answer :)

Actually the problem was exit code from the **bteq** to the bash.
Bash generally exits when it receives an exit code other than 0 for any subroutine call,bash behaviour.
More details about exit codes in bash http://bencane.com/2014/09/02/understanding-exit-codes-and-how-to-use-them-in-bash-scripts/
Now let's look into the above question and let's try to answer it,

```
bteq <<EOF!
    .set width 255
    .set format off
    .set titledashes off

    .logon ${HOST}/${USER}, ${PASSWORD};    

    .export report file=test_file.rpt;

#Assumption:- below query executes successfully      

SELECT count(*) from test_db.test_table;   /*this table contains 90 rows in my case*/

    .IF ERRORCODE <> 0 THEN .EXIT ERRORCODE;        
    .IF ACTIVITYCOUNT = 0 THEN .GOTO ALLOK

 #since ACTIVITYCOUNT will be other than 0(for above assumption to be true), code will execute exactly the line below 
 #thus bteq will exit with exit status 3 

    .LOGOFF;
    .EXIT 3;

    .LABEL ALLOK;
    .LOGOFF;
    .EXIT 0;

EOF!
```

Now if the above bteq returns 0,(i.e. `RET_FLAG = 0`), below code executes 
with RC `(return code) = 0`, since bash treats exit code 0 as success 
and if it returns values other than 0, below code doesn't executes and finally bash exits, because exit code other than 0 is treated as error by bash.

"**exit abandons the current shell**"-somewhere from stackoverflow

```
RET_FLAG=$?   
    print_msg "RET_FLAG: $RET_FLAG "   /*when return code other than 0 this line is not printed*/


if [ $RET_FLAG -gt 0 ]; #previously I was using if[$ -gt 0] 
then
     print_msg "Hello world get succeed" /* printing function */
     exit 1
fi
```

What can we do to handle such unwanted exits with exit codes other than 0 from sub-routine call or from bteq?
Sol:- we can use `set +e` at the very begnning of bteq, `set +e` stops bash from exiting even if exit code is other than 0, but this method is not recomended.
 The best practice is to use `trap`, please refer to the following documentation on how to use trap in bash 
http://linuxcommand.org/wss0160.php
http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html